# Display Names for Mean stack in DB

Tags: mongodb, angular, express, mean-stack

I am designing a small app in MEAN stack (Mongo + Express.js + Angular4 + Node.js) for a simple application.

I am designing a small collection users in DB and the sample record/document will look like

```
{
     "firstName": "John",
     "lastName": "Smith",
     "age": 25,
     "address":"12 Bedford St",
     "city":"Newport"
     "state":"MA"
     "active":true,
     "mobile":"7345980000",
     "car":"Honda City 2016"
}
```

Here we have keys like firstname, age, city etc., which needs to be displayed in UI as well. The UI display names will be like

**key: firstname      -   Display Name "First Name"**

**key: address        -   Display Name "Address"**

[image: Final Display in HTML Form]

As you can see in the image above, the Display Name is in Orange, Bold, Underline. These are different from keys, I want to store the **Display Name** along with **keys** in DB so that I can pull at runtime.

What is the correct strategy to store the key and Display Name in MongoDB, so that I can read the same and display appropriately in UI (Angular)?

Need best practices and suggestions.

Will this work?

```
{
    "personSchema": [
        {
            "key": "firstName",
            "displayName": "First Name",
            "internalCode": "101",
            "order": "001"
        },
        {
            "key": "lastName",
            "displayName": "Last Name",
            "internalCode": "201",
            "order": "002"
        },
        {
            "key": "age",
            "displayName": "Age",
            "internalCode": "301",
            "order": "003"
        },
        {
            "key": "address",
            "displayName": "Postal Address",
            "internalCode": "401",
            "order": "004"
        },
        {
            "key": "city",
            "displayName": "City",
            "internalCode": "501",
            "order": "005"
        },
        {
            "key": "state",
            "displayName": "State",
            "internalCode": "601",
            "order": "006"
        },
        {
            "key": "active",
            "displayName": "Active",
            "internalCode": "701",
            "order": "007"
        },
        {
            "key": "mobile",
            "displayName": "Mobile Number",
            "internalCode": "801",
            "order": "008"
        },
        {
            "key": "car",
            "displayName": "Car Make",
            "internalCode": "901",
            "order": "001"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: you can hard code in the UI directly.. what is that your trying to do

Comment: @Aravind - Edited and added a screenshot to explain clearly.

Comment: I know this is not exactly what you are asking but I would put these values in a json file in the mean application. almost like a properties file. This json file could contain key value pairs like you want. ("firstname" : "First Name"). Then the real data can live in the db.("firstname": "Tim")

Answer (score 0):

You can make your data like this....so u can use display name anywhere without duplicating data in document.

```
{
     "name": {
       "firstName" : "John",
       "lastName": "Smith"
     },
     "displayName": {
       "firstName" : "abc",
       "lastName": "xyz"
     },
     "age": 25,
     "address":"12 Bedford St",
     "city":"Newport"
     "state":"MA"
     "active":true,
     "mobile":"7345980000",
     "car":"Honda City 2016"
}
```